# Is it possible to use a lambda in combinations itertools? in order to do the combination with a specific element in a nested list

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, combinations, python-itertools

I have a csv file with actions in them:

```
Action Name,Price,Benefit
Action-1,20,5,1.0
Action-2,30,10,3.0
Action-3,50,15,7.5
Action-4,70,20,14.0
Action-5,60,17,10.2
Action-6,80,25,20.0
Action-7,22,7,1.54
Action-8,26,11,2.86
```

I transform it into a list:

```
rows = []
with open("files/actions_with_benefits.csv", 'r') as file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
header = next(csv_reader)
for row in csv_reader:
    rows.append(row)
print("header", header)
print("rows", rows)

rows:
[['Action-1', '20', '5', 1.0], ['Action-2', '30', '10', 3.0], ['Action-3', '50', '15', 7.5], ['Action-4', '70', '20', 14.0], ['Action-5', '60', '17', 10.2], ['Action-6', '80', '25', 20.0], ['Action-7', '22', '7', 1.54], ['Action-8', '26', '11', 2.86], ['Action-9', '48', '13', 6.24], ['Action-10', '34', '27', 9.18], ['Action-11', '42', '17', 7.14]]
```

I originally needed to calculate all the combinations of the different actions I could buy with 500 dollars (I could only buy 1 of each).

I used combinations to do this (I filtered my actions list to create a list with only the prices of the actions, which I called numbers):

```
target = 500

result = [seq for i in range(len(numbers), 0, -1)
      for seq in itertools.combinations(numbers, i)
      if sum(seq) == target]
```

But I was wondering if I could do that without filtering the other values like the name of the action for exemple and the benefit because I need them.
For exemple in the sort() method, you can use a lambda that allows you to sort on only 1 element in your list but returns the list sorted with all the elements.

Like in this exemple I found:
Input : [['rishav', 10], ['akash', 5], ['ram', 20], ['gaurav', 15]]

```
def Sort(sub_li):

sub_li.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
return sub_li

sub_li =[['rishav', 10], ['akash', 5], ['ram', 20], ['gaurav', 15]]

print(Sort(sub_li))
Output : [['akash', 5], ['rishav', 10], ['gaurav', 15], ['ram', 20]]
```

Do you know if there is a possibility to do this with itertools.combinations?

Thank you in advance for your help and have a lovely day

Comment: Yes it's possible, no you shouldn't. (`sum doesn't support a transformation function, you could use `map` but then shouldn't use `lambda`.)

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple alternative: run two `combinations` in parallel. Probably faster than stuffing a `lambda` into `sum` (though I guess speed isn't an issue, otherwise you wouldn't use brute force anyway)

```
result = [rowseq
          for i in range(len(numbers), 0, -1)
          for seq, rowseq in zip(
              itertools.combinations(numbers, i),
              itertools.combinations(rows, i)
          )
          if sum(seq) == target]
```

Comment: hello! I get this error when I try your solution:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Comment: @Claire I think you made a mistake in how you used it. I'll have to see your code in order to fix it.